# Split the string in to center

Tags: java, android

I want to split this string: **Sun Apr 12 17:56:00 GMT+05:00 2015**. I only get **17:56**.
I tried this:

```
String[] splitStr = str.split("\\s+");
```

Comment: ignore my mistakes new here and in android

Answer (score 1):

You could do it by String as well as parsing the date:

By String you can do it like:

```
String str = "Sun Apr 12 17:56:00 GMT+05:00 2015";
String time = str.split(" ")[3];
System.out.println(time.substring(0, time.lastIndexOf(':')));
```

By dateFormat you could use the pattern to parse the date and then get hour and minutes from it like with pattern below:

```
String str = "Sun Apr 12 17:56:00 GMT+05:00 2015";
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd kk:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
Date result =  df.parse(target);
```

then to work with date use:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date);
cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
```